# ContainerView of TableViewController not working?

Tags: uitableview, uicontainerview

I want to display static cells in a ContainerView but every time the app runs it crashes at start. I read somewhere your unable to use static cells in UITableView but said it should work in a Container View to UITableViewController. Thanks for any input.

```
2014-01-01 15:44:56.294 InterestingGame[24199:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x8935970> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key second.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0173d5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014c08b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x017cd6a1 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x011819ee -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x010edcfb _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 88
    5   Foundation                          0x010ed253 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 267
    6   Foundation                          0x0114f70a -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x004d0a15 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 106
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x014d27d2 -[NSObject performSelector:] + 62
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x01738b6a -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 314
    10  UIKit                               0x004cf56e -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1417
    11  UIKit                               0x00762a2f -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 220
    12  UIKit                               0x00762ba8 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 74
    13  UIKit                               0x0022e44c -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 79
    14  UIKit                               0x0022e6e9 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 245
    15  UIKit                               0x0022d28f -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 543
    16  UIKit                               0x0024187c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3447
    17  UIKit                               0x00241de9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 85
    18  UIKit                               0x0022f025 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 736
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x036942f6 _PurpleEventCallback + 776
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x03693e01 PurpleEventCallback + 46
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x016b8d65 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 53
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x016b8a9b __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 523
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x016e377c __CFRunLoopRun + 2156
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x016e2ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x016e28db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    26  UIKit                               0x0022cadd -[UIApplication _run] + 840
    27  UIKit                               0x0022ed3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  InterestingGame                     0x0000473d main + 141
    29  libdyld.dylib                       0x01d79725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: @Paul.s libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Add the full stack trace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That exception is pointing to an outlet being hooked up in interface builder that may no longer have an underlying property.

You may have previously had a `second` property declared in code that was then hooked up in a xib/storyboard. You will then have removed this property or renamed it and not broken the connection in the xib/storyboard. You need to go to the connections panel in interface builder and remove the broken connection